How to determine if a &str passed to a trait method has a 'static lifetime in Rust to avoid unnecessary copies?
I'm implementing a method from an external trait, which accepts a &str as an argument. I want to determine if the passed &str has a 'static lifetime (i.e., if it is a &'static str) or if it has a shorter lifetime.
My goal is to avoid unnecessary copying for static strings. If the string is 'static, I would prefer to borrow it, but if it has a shorter lifetime, I will handle it differently (e.g., by making an owned copy).
Since the method signature is part of an external trait, I cannot modify it to explicitly require a 'static lifetime or change its behavior. However, in my implementation of the method, I would like to check whether the string reference is a &'static str or not.
Here's a simplified example:
trait ExternalTrait {
    fn my_function(&mut self, s: &str);
}

struct MyStruct;

impl ExternalTrait for MyStruct {
    fn my_function(&mut self, s: &str) {
        if is_static_str(s) {
            println!("This is a static string");
        } else {
            println!("This is not a static string");
        }
    }
}

fn is_static_str(s: &str) -> bool {
    // Is it possible to determine if `s` is a &'static str to avoid copying?
}

Even if there isn't a generalized solution, I'm open to platform-specific approaches. For example, on certain platforms, static strings may be stored in a specific address range. But I would like to avoid using unsafe code if possible.

In general this is impossible in Rust. But maybe some specific solution would be avaliable to you, if you showed what you want to do with this string. How are you planning on storing it.

Have you looked at Cow<'static, str>? Maybe this is what you want.

@AleksanderKrauze I want to store it in an enum, something like
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq)]
enum MyString{
Owned(Box),
Static(&'static str),
Ref(Arc),
}

You cannot. What you can do is extend the trait with a version for static strings:
trait ExternalTraitExt : ExternalTrait {
    fn my_function_static(&mut self, s: &'static str);
}

Then you can call my_function_static when appropriate. Unfortunately this doesn't work for external consumers of the original trait, but that is just fundamentally not supported in Rust today.
The concept you want is called "lifetime specialization", and it currently is not even on the roadmap for the specialization efforts.

Thanks for the RFC link; it clarifies things. Unfortunately, I can't extend the trait since I register my implementation with an external crate, which provides ExternalTrait and uses it to invoke my methods. Specifically, this relates to the tracing::field::Visit::record_str method here: https://docs.rs/tracing-core/latest/tracing_core/field/trait.Visit.html

@LKB Then I'm afraid you've ran out of options. Perhaps you can convince the tracing-core people that they can add a record_static_str method to that trait with a default implementation that defers to record_str, but they might reject your feature request as being a micro-optimization.
